# ¿Porqué no suma correctamente?

Tags: javascript

¿Porqué la suma de (1.9 + 0.95) da error?

Este error se da con algunos derivados de la operación como (2.9 + 0.95) o (1.9 + 0.958)

En cambio si uso 1.95 + 0.9 si lo hace bien.

[image: suma de dos valores errónea]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error se debe a que los números en coma flotante se almacenan en binario y algunos números decimales no se pueden representar con precisión en binario. Por lo tanto, cuando se realizan operaciones con estos números, pueden ocurrir errores de redondeo.

Para evitar este problema, puedes usar el método `toFixed()` para redondear los números antes de realizar operaciones con ellos. Por ejemplo:

```
var num1 = 1.9;
var num2 = 0.95;

var resultado = (num1 + num2).toFixed(2);

console.log(resultado); // "2.85"
```